# Listview using JSON from RESTApi Android

Tags: android, json, listview

I'm trying to fill a listviews content with JSON Objects obtained from a REST service I've made.

```
JSONArray users = new JSONArray(result);
jsonList = users;
```

I retrieve the JSONArray and convert that array into an `ArrayList<String>`, which I'm using to fill my listview with.

```
try{
    int length = jsonList.length();
    List<String> contentList = new ArrayList<String>(length);
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
        contentList.add(jsonList.getString(i));
    }

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, contentList));
    } catch(Exception e){

    }
```

But when I run the application, there is no data at all in the listview.

I don't really know whether this is a problem because of the way I populate my listview content, or if it's my XML that has some problems.

XML FILES:
(activity_main.xml)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/listView" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I'm a bit of a newcomer when it comes to Android.

Comment: Please post the structure of json

Comment: `[{"name":"Christian Haase","_id":"54eda37aa4e01feebaf9c66a","__v":0},{"name":"Line Mungaard","_id":"54edde9ba4e01feebaf9c66b","__v":0}]`

Comment: first of all you need to set the field item in the getString method for example if you want the Listview to display the name you have to say `contentList.add(jsonList.getString("name"));` and also you have to parse JSONObject and JSONResponse to string

Comment: What do you wish to publish in ListView? `name` or `_id` or `_v`?

Comment: like: `Christian Haase 54eda37aa4e01feebaf9c66a` ?

Comment: Exactly. I'm working on a bigger project, but I just want to test with this first

Answer (score 0):

Here, the *JSONArray* contains objects. Each object has items *name*, *_id*, etc. If you want to publish the *name* in the *ListView*, create JSONObject* in the *for* loop and get the *value* for *name* using `getString("name")`. It's a good habit to check for the presence of an item using `has(String id)`.

```
int length = jsonList.length();
List<String> contentList = new ArrayList<String>(length);
try {
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonList.getJSONObject(i);
        if(jsonObject.has("name")) {
            contentList.add(jsonObject.getString("name"));
        }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {

}
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, contentList));
```

Comment: I tested it. It's working for me. Print the _JSONArray_ just before _for_ loop using `Log.d("TAG", jsonList.toString(2));`. Check the _json_ is the correct or not.

Comment: I still can't seem to get it to work. Does your xml files look the same as mine?

Comment: Yes! I changed my xml to be same as yours. I can see the ListView. However, remove `android:orientation="vertical"`. Did you print the JSONArray?

Comment: I know that I'm adding the JSON objects to the array since I'm not getting an ArrayOutOfIndex error, so the JSON objects are in the JSON array. I feel like this could be a mistake in the design of the ListView, in my activity_main?

Comment: Yes, I printed the JSONArray using the `Log.d("TAG", jsonList.toString(2));`

Comment: _I know that I'm adding the JSON objects to the array since I'm not getting an ArrayOutOfIndex error, so the JSON objects are in the JSON array_. Not sure what exactly you want to achieve.

Comment: Well, I'm not getting an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception on my JSONArray when I try to add them to the new array, so the JSONObjects must be put into the new array `contentList`

Answer (score -1):

```
JSONArray response;
        List<String> contentList = new ArrayList<String>(length);
        try {
            response = new JSONArray(respons);
            for(int i=0;i<response.length();i++){
                JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                String name = obj.getString("name");
                contentList.add(name);
            }


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataArray = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, contentList);

        listView.setAdapter(dataArray);
```

Where 'respons' is your JSON RESPONSE (MAIN NODE).
According to your JSON Structure the above code will work.

Comment: This didn't work. It's still not showing anything. this is the JSON that I get from the REST service: `[{"name":"Christian Haase","_id":"54eda37aa4e01feebaf9c66a","__v":0},{"name":"Line Mungaard","_id":"54edde9ba4e01feebaf9c66b","__v":0}]`

Comment: This wont work. _ArrayIndexOutOfBounds_ exception here.

Comment: @ShifarShifz : You created a String array `name` of size 1. `name[i]` will give exception if `i > 0`